# First remove then add href attribute to anchor tag

Tags: jquery, href

I have an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ToggleLinks('boothsizeDiv');">
```

In the same function I want to first remove the href attribute based on some condition, and then reattach it back based on another condition.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aenu/) for everyone :) .

Comment: Try attr() and removeAttr()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions are kind of your own responsibility, I can't guess them, but you can manage the attributes of a thing with jQuery using the `attr` method, such as...

Getting the `href`:

```
var href = $("#url").attr("href");
```

Setting the `href`:

```
$("#url").attr("href", "some link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `attr` method to set the `href` value.

```
<a id="link" href="#" onclick="ToggleLinks('boothsizeDiv');">

 $("#link").click(function() {
     var element = $(this);
        if (yourCondition) {
             element.attr("href", "#");
        }  else {
             element.attr("href", "value");
       }
 });
```

Alternatively you could do it in your ToggleLinks function:

```
 function ToggleLinks() {
      var element = document.getElementById("link");
      if (condition) { element.href = "#"; }
      else { element.href = "yourvalue"; }
 }
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/